# Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices - The request failed. The network name cannot be found

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I have a c# program and using Exchange Service to send emails. When hitting `emailMeassage.SendAndSaveCopy()` method, it throws an exception saying that 'the network name cannot be found'.  Any idea what's the potential cause of this exception? And what does the `network` mean here? The Exchange Service URL can be discovered without a problem. I spent quite a bit of time doing research but it seems there is not much relevant resource.

```
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices - The request failed. The network name cannot be found.
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.BuildEwsHttpWebRequest()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ValidateAndEmitRequest(IEwsHttpWebRequest& request)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MultiResponseServiceRequest`1.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.InternalCreateItems(IEnumerable`1 items, FolderId parentFolderId, Nullable`1 messageDisposition, Nullable`1 sendInvitationsMode, ServiceErrorHandling errorHandling)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Item.InternalCreate(FolderId parentFolderId, Nullable`1 messageDisposition, Nullable`1 sendInvitationsMode)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage.InternalSend(FolderId parentFolderId, MessageDisposition messageDisposition)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage.SendAndSaveCopy()
   at GTR.Helpers.EmailUtility.SenEmail(String Subject, String Body, String[] ToEmails, String[] CCEmails, String[] BCCs, String[] ReplyTo, String AttachmentName, String AttachmentContent, String FromEmail) in F:\Projects\GTR\Dev\GTR\Helpers\EmailUtility.cs:line 146
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not really an EWS error its an error that is bubbling up from the local O/S I would suggest reading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-server/remote/network-name-cannot-found-fqdn-remote-computer.

A simple way to test if that was the issue would be to specify the IP address of the Exchange endpoint manually (no autodiscover) while ignoring any SSL errors. eg

```
ServicePointManager
.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += 
(sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
service.Url = new Uri("https://192.168.1.2/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
```

If that works then you know you have an O/S issue

Comment: Hi @Glen, I've tried to use the IP address of the exchange server instead of AutoDiscover like what you suggested in the answer, and it still gives me the same error saying 'The request failed. The network name cannot be found'.

Comment: I would try running the ewsEditor https://github.com/dseph/EwsEditor/releases on that machine and see if you get the same error. Sounds like an IP6 issue